# Unexpected tag T_ECHO in inline if

Tags: php

I have something like this in one of my views

```
<li <?php $isCurrent ? echo 'class="current"' : ''?> >
    <a href="SOME_LINK" class="SOME_CLASS">SOME_TEXT</a>
</li>
```

This causes a syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO. Changing `echo` for `print` solves the issue, but I would like to understand why I cannot use `echo`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't use this construct that way. The [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) is not an "if" block, but returns a value based on whether the condition is fulfilled or not.

You want to change the structure:

```
<?php echo  ($isCurrent ? 'class="current"' : '') ?>
```

it works with `print()` because that is a function with a return value. It is however not what you want, because the first `echo` will print out the result of `print` which makes no sense.

It doesn't work with `echo` because echo is not a function, but a language construct.

Comment: `echo` is a language construct and does not need parenthesis

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
<?php $isCurrent ? echo 'class="current"' : ''?>
```

to

```
<?php echo $isCurrent ? 'class="current"' : ''?>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php):

> echo() is not actually a function (it
>   is a language construct), so you are
>   not required to use parentheses with
>   it. echo() (unlike some other language
>   constructs) does not behave like a
>   function, so it cannot always be used
>   in the context of a function.
>   Additionally, if you want to pass more
>   than one parameter to echo(), the
>   parameters must not be enclosed within
>   parentheses.

This instead works fine:

```
<?php $isCurrent ? print('class="current"') : ''?>
```

Anyway, it's bad coding. Better is

```
<?php echo $isCurrent ? 'class="current"' : ''?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this small fix will solve your problem:

```
<li <?php echo ($isCurrent ? 'class="current"' : '')?> >
    <a href="SOME_LINK" class="SOME_CLASS">SOME_TEXT</a>
</li>
```

Comment: -1 for using short opening tags - a really bad idea and massively limits code portability, as (by default) they are disabled.

Comment: I didn't know that short opening tags were disabled by default, I edited my answer so that the code will work with the regular php-tags

Comment: Wicked. I can't unvote my downvote unless you edit your answer again

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier to read and handle imho

```
<?php printf('<li%s><a href="%s" class="%s">%s</a></li>',
              $isCurrent ? ' class="current"' : '',
              $someLink, $someClass, $someText);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would drop the ternary operator and the empty printed string altogether and write:

```
<?php
$isCurrent and print 'class="current"';
?>
```